# Java double precision sum trouble

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I would like to know why I get this error. (this is Display log of Eclipse debug)

```
var
     (double) 2.8
tot.getIva()
     (java.lang.Double) 0.17
var+tot.get()
     (double) 2.9699999999999998
```

I can not understand why I did not get simply 2.97!

Comment: Read this Q&A - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: Or this Q&A - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257166/java-floats-and-doubles-how-to-avoid-that-0-0-0-1-0-1-0-9000001

Comment: Also, semi-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423545/sum-of-decimal-number-in-java

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you wanted `2.97`, you should have used [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

`double`s are stored as fractions in *binary*, not decimal.  So `3.75`, for example, is just stored as `2^1 + 2^0 + 2^(-1) + 2^(-2)`.

`2.8` and `0.17` cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions, so there's going to be some rounding error.

You may also find [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the precision of floating point types in java (float and double). If you need indefinite precision you should try using `BigDecimal` instead of `double`.