# WCF decimals issue

Tags: java, wcf

I do have a strange problem on the communication between a Java client application and a .NET WCF Service.

The application transmits an amount like 10.99 while the service gets something like 10.990000000000000000001234567 (27 decimals after comma ?.....)

I wanted to ask what could be the problem (I'm not even sure whether it's on the Java side, what I know is that the dto on the .NET side gets a decimal number which looks like that)

Comment: It could be a problem with Java about handling the double values. More info: [Java double precision sum trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10786587/1065197)

Comment: I have been told they set the amount as BigDecimal on the Dto they transmit to us. Could the problem be somewhere in the WCF service ?...

Comment: There was a conversion of BigDecimal from double, indeed (through BidDecimal constructor)