# Java double addition rounding off

Tags: java, precision

In java following expression results into

```
new Double(1.0E22) + new Double(3.0E22)  = 4.0E22
```

but

```
new Double(1.0E22) + new Double(4.0E22)  = 4.9999999999999996E22
```

I was expecting it to be `5.0E22`. The Double limit is `1.7976931348623157E308`. 
Appreciate your help. My machine's architecture is x64 and JVM is also 64 bit.

Comment: Take a look at the answer of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786587/java-double-precision-sum-trouble

Comment: 1) new Double(1.0E22) + new Double(3.0E22) makes no sense since it's equivalent to 1.0E22 + 3.0E22

Comment: The problem is that `5^23` has 54 significant bits, `0x2a5a058fc295ed`, but `double` has only 53. So `5.0e22` gets rounded down to `(5^23 - 1)*2^22`.

Comment: @DanielFischer but double's max value is 1.7976931348623157E308. So i am safely within that range. Still why am i seeing the rounding off?

Comment: Because `double` has only 53 bits of precision, but `5.0e22` needs 54. `double` can only exactly represent numbers that need 53 bits of precision or less. `1.0e22`, `2.0e22`, `3.0e22` and `4.0e22` all need only 52 or 53 (3.0e22) bits of precision to be exactly represented (and the exponent is small enough), so those are exactly represented.

Comment: @Mik378 Thanks, BigDecimal worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the planet of floating point units. Unfortunately, in a real world, you have to give up some precision to get speed and breadth of representation. You cannot avoid that: `double` is only an *approximate* representation. Actually, you cannot represent a number but with *finite* precision. Still, it's a good approximation: less than 0.00000000001% error. This has nothing to do with `double` upper limits, rather with CPU limits, try doing some more math with Python:

```
>>> 4.9999999999999996 / 5.
1.0
>>> 5. - 4.9999999999999996
0.0
```

See? As a side note, never check for equality on `double`, use approximate equality:

```
if ((a - b) < EPSILON)
```

Where `EPSILON` is a very small value. Probably Java library has something more appropriate, but you get the idea.

If you are insterested in some theory, the standard for floating point operations is [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that you can reduce floating point errors, e.g. [pairwise summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation) and [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm), but neither of these will help you precisely represent a number like 5.0E22 - as Stefano Sanfilippo stated in his answer, that's due to the limits of what you can represent in using floating point, as opposed to a problem with the algorithm used to achieve the answer.  To represent 5.0E22 you should either use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) or else use a library that has a `Rational` data type, e.g. [JScience](http://jscience.org/).