# Generate a Random Double With Specific 6 Digit decimal

Tags: java, random, double

I want to create a Random Double with 6 decimal digits precision, buts this code doesnt do this always :/ Where is the problem of this code?

```
double random = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.6f", new Random().nextDouble())); 
            double SP = 0.0 + (random * (7.0 - 0.0));
```

here is the random number that has been generated by this code for 10 times:

- 6.321637
- 6.971019999999996
- 0.763686
- 0.14724500000000001
- 0.240456
- 3.268468
- 2.112775
- 2.5137419999999997
- 4.637668
- 4.712155

Here is Full code With Correction that @javaguy Answered  .
And Now It Works: (But Attention To Change 'StartNumber' And 'EndNumber' like this : 2.5 )

```
import java.util.Random;
double random = new Random().nextDouble(); 
double N = SartNumber + (random * (EndNumber - StartNumber)); 
N = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.6f", N)); //N Is Your Number
```

Comment: Java double rounding error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179427/how-to-resolve-a-java-rounding-double-issue

Comment: This is not an error, this is because of the precision a double can get is not accurate for all numbers, you can look into BigDecimal.

Comment: The problem is in Double precision. See [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786587/java-double-precision-sum-trouble) for more details on this.
I recommend you use formatting when printing results to achieve required amount of digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are multiplying with `double` after formatting, so you are loosing your previous format, so change your code as shown below which does the formatting at the end, once after all calculations are done:

```
double random = new Random().nextDouble(); 
double SP = 0.0 + (random * (7.0 - 0.0)); 
SP = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.6f", SP)); //now do format
```

Comment: If this is the case, why does it only happen sometimes?

Comment: It depends upon the number generated

Comment: Thanks Man!! It Worked!!  But As "pgmann" Asked too, Why just Some Times Happend?

Comment: Look here for double Rounding issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179427/how-to-resolve-a-java-rounding-double-issue

Comment: So always apply the formatting at the end of calculations, if u r using double